# Conditions for the intersection of two hyperellipsoids in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to be empty?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

Given two hyperellipsoids in $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by the quadratic forms
$$
(x-c_1)^\top A_1(x-c_1)=1
$$

and

$$
(x-c_2)^\top A_2(x-c_2)=1
$$
with $A_1$ and $A_2$ being positive definite. What are the necessary and sufficient conditions on $A_1, A_2, c_1$ and $c_2$ such that the intersection of the two surfaces is empty?

Comment: One must be strictly contained in the other. I would guess you probably only need to test the intersections of the eigenvectors of $A_i$ with the surface of the hyperellipsoids.